# Select validation between fields

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.1

***What am I trying to do?***
I have three fields (1 hidden, an id) and the user must complete one of the other two in order to pass validation.
So the user should fail validation if both fields are empty, but pass if one is completed.

*1  2  3*
A  0  B  True
A  B  0  True
A  0  0  False

I'm using CakePHP **v2.1.3** so have access to the new validation rule enhancements.

***The problem***
I can't seem to find a reliable way to check both fields at the same time. I have so far tried looking at `$this->data` from the `model` and have found that validation is only passing a single instance of the data at a time. So there doesn't seem to be a way to compare the fields.

***What I have so far***

```
/**
 * Custom validation to see if either of the two fields are set, if neither are, then we fail, if at least one is, we pass
 * @param array $check
 * @return boolean 
 */
public function checkAttributes($check){
    var_dump($check);
    var_dump($this->data);
    echo "<hr>";

    // Check for an id value picked from a list
    if(@is_numeric($check['attribute_value_id']) && isset($this->data['AdvertAttributeValue']['attribute_value_id'])){
        return true;
    }

    // Check for a date value selected
    if(@is_array($check['attribute_value_text']) && isset($this->data['AdvertAttributeValue']['attribute_value_text'])){
        return true;
    }

    // Check for a text value
    if(@is_string($check['attribute_value_text']) && isset($this->data['AdvertAttributeValue']['attribute_value_text'])){
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

This doesn't seem to do the trick as I think it can't check `$this->data` because the instance of it doesn't contain all the relevant fields.

***The data***
I should also mention that I am passing a large numeric array in. So these fields appear multiple times on the page, currently 12 dimensions. So accessing them directly through `$this->data` will be hard as they are not named dimensions, but are `$this->data['Model'][<num>]['field'] = value`

---

***Validation***

```
public $validate = array(
    'attribute_value_id'=>array(
        'notempty'=>array(
            'rule'=>'checkAttributes',
            'message'=>'Please select a value for your attribute',
            'required'=>true,
        ),
    ),
    'attribute_value_text'=>array(
        'notempty'=>array(
            'rule'=>'checkAttributes',
            'message'=>'You must enter text for this attribute',
            'required'=>true,
        ),
    )
);
```

***Data dump***
Here I'll show the output of the `var_dump()` above. I have two validation rules in my Model, one for `attribute_value_id` and also one for `attribute_value_text`

```
// An id field selected from a list
array // $check
  'attribute_value_id' => string '1' (length=1)
array // $this->data
  'AdvertAttributeValue' => 
    array
      'attribute_value_id' => string '1' (length=1)
      'id' => string '' (length=0)

// A text field
// Validating first time around on the id field
array // $check
  'attribute_value_id' => string '' (length=0)
array // $this->data
  'AdvertAttributeValue' => 
    array
      'attribute_value_id' => string '' (length=0)
      'id' => string '' (length=0)
      'attribute_value_text' => string '50' (length=2)
// Validating second time around on the text field
array // $check
  'attribute_value_text' => string '50' (length=2)
array // $this->data
  'AdvertAttributeValue' => 
    array
      'attribute_value_id' => string '' (length=0)
      'id' => string '' (length=0)
      'attribute_value_text' => string '50' (length=2)  
// A date field
array // $check
  'attribute_value_id' => string '' (length=0)
array // $this->data
  'AdvertAttributeValue' => 
    array
      'attribute_value_id' => string '' (length=0)
      'id' => string '' (length=0)
      'attribute_value_text' => 
        array
          'month' => string '06' (length=2)
          'day' => string '28' (length=2)
          'year' => string '2012' (length=4)
```

Comment: At what stage is this validation taking place? If, for example, it's during saving, `$this->data` ought to contain whatever you passed into `Model::save()` from the controller. What do you mean when you say "that validation is only passing a single instance of the data"?

Comment: @eaj This is during save. By passing a single instance, I mean a single array dimension. So in my numeric array only a single dimension is passed to the custom validation function. So if you have say 5 fields, you'll only get one passed in at a time. I'll add a dump.

Comment: If `$this->data` doesn't contain all the information you need to validate (as you say in your question), surely that's because you're not passing it all into `Model::save()` from your controller? As I understand it, when you call `save()`, the model's `$this->data` is set to the data you pass in. This, in turn, is passed to `validate()`. (Then again maybe you've solved this as it's been two weeks now; I've been away.)

Comment: I'm using `saveAll()` which is probably why the data is different. I ended up coding around it using javascript! So not really solved yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `saveAll()` method just calls `saveMany()` or `saveAssociated()` as appropriate. These methods will, by default, attempt to validate all of the data before saving any of it (via a call to `validateMany()`). However, as you can see in [the source](http://api20.cakephp.org/view_source/model#line-2130), that function validates each item individually, so the validation code won't have access to other records.

As I understand it, you need to cross-validate between multiple records before you save them. Although I've never done that, it sounds like a case for validation in the controller. You can make calls to `Model::validate()` or `Model::validateAll()` to ensure internal consistency of records. Then your controller can also implement whatever logic is necessary for your cross-record validation. Once that's done, you can make the save call with validation disabled:

```
$this->myModel->saveAll($this->request->data, array('validate'=>false));
```

Note that before you do any of this, you'll have to set your data to the model:

```
$this->myModel->set($this->request->data);
```

I realize this puts a lot of extra code in the controller that should ideally be in the model. I suppose it's possible that it could be done via one of the model callbacks, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: This sounds like a logical approach as it can be broken out into a component, plugin or behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of Model::$data or Model::beforeValidate().

Comment: Care to expand your answer to make it helpful?